# Clarification on a Theorem on Relations(very basic and trival)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> Suppose $R$ is a relation on a set $A$, that is, $R$ is a relation from a set $A$ to itself. Then $R◦R$, the composition of $R$ with itself, is always deﬁned.

The Above is from "Schaum's Theory and Problems of Discrete Mathematics"

Consider the set $A= \{1,2\}$
$$R = \{(1,2)\}$$

How is $R◦R$ defined?

It seems to contradict this statement from the same book:

> Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be sets, and let $R$ be a relation from $A$ to $B$ and let $S$ be a relation from $B$ to $C$. That is, $R$ is a subset of $A×B$ and $S$ is a subset of $B ×C$. Then $R$ and $S$ give rise to a relation from $A$ to $C$ denoted by $R◦S$ and deﬁned by: $a(R◦S)c$ if for some $b ∈ B$ we have $aRb$ and bSc. That is , $$R◦S =\{(a,c)|\exists b \in B : (a,b) \in R \& (b,c) ∈ S\} $$

Comment: A relation on $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$. Your $\{\,1,2\,\}$ is not a relation on $A$.

Comment: Doesn't $$A \times A = \{1,1\} \{1,2} \{2,1\} \{2,2\}$$? In that case, shouldn't my $R$ be a relation?

Comment: A relation on $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$. $A\times A$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ with $x$ in $A$ and $y$ in $A$. Your 1, 2 is not an ordered pair, nor is it a list of ordered pairs, so $\{\,1,2\,\}$ is not a set of ordered pairs, so it's not a relation on $A$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I've edited my question. Isn't $(1,2)$ an ordered pair. Doesn't that make $R$ a relation. What am I missing?

Comment: If $R = \{(1,2)\}$, then $R \circ R = \emptyset$, which is again a relation.

Comment: But doesn't that contradict the definition, in the textbook. $\phi$ may be $\subset A \times A$ and thus a relation. Doesn't considering $\phi$  relation, mean that $\forall A, B ,C R: A \rightarrow B, S: B \rightarrow C, R \circle S$$ is defined.

Comment: As mrp says, yes, $R\circ R$ is defined, and when you calculate what it is, it turns out to be the empty set. Just as zero is a number, so the empty set is a relation. Call it the empty relation, if you like.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So the composition of any two relations$[$and by extension any $n$ relations$($through induction$)]$is ***always*** defined?

Comment: Any two relations, provided the codomain of the first is the domain of the second. You give the definition in your question!

Comment: The book only says $ R\circR$ is defined, and didn't generaluse which caused my dichotomy.

Comment: But... you quote the generalisation and say it's from the same book?

Comment: If $\phi$ os considered a relation, then doesn't that mean that $\forall R, S, R \circ S$ is defined?

Comment: No. As I said, the codomain of $R$ must be the domain of $S$ in order for $R\circ S$ to be defined. Same as for any composition of functions.

Comment: So, are we OK now?

Comment: Yes. I have accepted your explanation.

Comment: Good. So, let me encourage you to write up and post an answer to your question, based on your current understanding of the mathematics involved. You can even accept your own answer. This may seem odd, but it is encouraged by the rules of the site (and it keeps the question from popping up at random times in the future, and it gives you practice in writing up amthematical reasoning).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I still have one topic I need clarification on. Please see my 'answer'

Answer (score 0):

$R\circ R$ is, in this case, $\varnothing$. The case of $R\circ R$ is just the special case of the second quoted piece of text where $A=B=C=\{1,2\}$ and $R=S=\{(1,2)\}$. Notice that it is true that every ordered pair that *is* a member of $\varnothing$ is an ordered pair from $A\times A$, vacuously.

You can check that the definition of $R\circ S$ specializes in this case to $\{(a,c)|\exists b\in A:(a,b)\in R\wedge (b,c)\in R\}$. How many pairs are there in $A\times A$ that meet this condition?

Answer (score 0):

***DISCLAIMER***
This is an ad hoc explanation that conveys my understanding(and misuderstandings) of this theorem. I wrote this due to @GerryMyerson 's suggestion to that effect.

By the definition of the composition of two relations $R$ $\&$ $S$ defined on $A \rightarrow B$ and $B \rightarrow C$ respectively $A, B, C$ being non-empty, we have; $R \circ S$ defined as :
$$(a,c)| \exists b \in B: (a,b) \in R \& (b,c) \in S$$

Now the empty set $\phi \subset D$ where $D$ is any set.

The definition of a relation is a subset of the product set.

It is vacuously true, that the empty relation is a subset of the product set of any set $A$. The 'counter example' in the question is merely a case of $R \circ R$ being the empty relation. Thus $R \circ R$ is always defined.

$$R \circ R = (NULL, c), \exists b \in A: (NULL, b) \in R \&  (b, c) \in R)$$

In this case, $b$ is $1$ and $c$ is $2$.

I'm 'guessing' $(NULL, e) \& (e, NULL)$ is considered $\phi$ but $(NULL, NULL)$ is not. $e$ representing any element of a set$.\tag{*}$

In particular, any for any two relations their composition is defined if the domain of the first is the codomain of the second. This means a scenario in which the first equation as the same domain and range, i.e it is a relation on a set.

We get:
$$R \circ S = (a,c)| \exists b \in A: (a,b) \in R \& (b,c) \in S$$

The empty relation is considered a relation, so given that of the sets $A, B, C; A = B$ $A, B, C$ being non-empty.

We'll at least have 
$$ R \circ S = (NULL, c), \exists b \in A: (NULL, b) \in R \& (b, c) \in S$$

**OR**
$$ R \circ S = (a, NULL), \exists b \in A: (a, b) \in R \& (b, NULL) \in S$$

The symbol $NULL$ denoting the element of the empty set? Or an empty element. Anyway, it's an Adhoc symbol I made to convey my understanding of this theorem.

$(*)$ The reason why I said I guess $(NULL,NULL)$ is not considered  $\phi$ was because if it was then the composition of all relations would be defined.

***EDIT***
I rethought my explanation, and found out that it doesn't resolve my fundamental dissonance:

> If the composition of two relations is considered defined when $R\circ R = \phi$, then doesn't that mean that the composition of all relations is defined?

I was told, that it's ***only*** when the domain of the first is the codomain of the second. I guess that's true, but don't understand why that's true. Even my adhoc model fails to explain it.

A counter example:

Consider the sets $A, B, C$
$ A = \{1\}, B = \{2,3\} $ $\& C = \{9\}$
$R: A \rightarrow B, S: B \rightarrow C $ 
$R =\{(1,2)\}, S = \{(3,9)\}$

$ \exists 2 \in B: (1,2) \in R$ $ \& (2,NULL) [\phi] \in S$

$$\therefore R\circ S = \{(1,NULL)\} || \{(NULL, 3)\}$$

Thus my ad hoc model fails, but it was only a model meant to try to.convey my understanding of the answer that the empty relation is considered as definitive of the composition of two relations. I still can't understand how that answer ***doesn't*** imply that any two relations are defined.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I've taken up your suggestion. Please review my answer.

Comment: You're being careless in the use of notation, e.g., when you write $A=1$, $B=2,3$ when you really mean $A=\{\,1\,\}$, $B=\{\,2,3\,\}$, and $R=(1,2)$ when you mean $R=\{\,(1,2)\,\}$. Also, $R\circ S$ is defined only when the *codomain* of $R$ is the *domain* of $S$ – you keep writing it the other way around. And $R\circ S=\{\,(a,c)\mid \exists b\in B:(a,b)\in R{\rm\ and\ }(b,c)\in S\,\}$. I don't know what you mean by NULL. In your last example, $R\circ S$ is the empty set, since there are no $a$ in $A$, $b\in B$, $c\in C$ such that $(a,b)$ is in $R$ and $(b,c)$ is in $S$.